# Get All Users password of Google Apps Account Using PHP Client Library

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-workspace, google-directory-api

I know guys get account details.But if i try account details received except password.

My code is:

```
$optParams = array(
  //'customer' => 'www2',
  'customer' => 'my_customer',
   'maxResults' => 50,
   'orderBy' => 'email',
);
$results = $service->users->listUsers($optParams);
```

Please help me

Comment: You're trying to fetch user's passwords? Seriously?

Comment: yes, Is any problem there. If initial i want to get all my gsuite users details with their password using admin id for my own web site DB

Comment: No, you will never and should never get the passwords. They are not available to you.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update  In this url update is possible . then why password retrieve not.

Comment: It's a major security risk to retrieve your users' passwords. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A gsuite [user resource](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users#resource) does contain a password filed.  However passwords are not stored clear text they are hash values.  Seeing this hash value would not help you.

Even as admin of gsuite you are never going to be able to see a users password.  A persons password is their own and even admins have no right seeing them.

While [user update](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update) will allow you to set a users password this field is write able but that does not mean that its going to be readable.

This is clearly stated in the documentation  ([user resource](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users#resource) )

> The password value is never returned in the API's response body.

Comment: Is user update is password possible in php client library

Comment: Yes using the user.update method you can update the users password the field is writeable

Comment: Im using this method to get all user in my gsuite account https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/php

Comment: this might help its for setting a password on a new user but its close https://michaelseiler.net/2014/12/16/google-admin-sdk-api-with-php/